# How should I update my Shopify theme to 2.0

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template, liquid-template

I have bought a theme 3 years ago and I've customised it quite highly, adding and editing old / new templates, sections and snippets, CSS and a bit of Javascript. There have been several new versions to the theme and I'd like to update it to be in sync with Shopify's 2.0 Theme structure.

My question is how would I go about it? I downloaded the newest version of the theme.

Comment: Need to do the all work manually or hire someone else. who port the changes to a new theme.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.